# Pact testing using random port with jUnit5 and SpringBoot

Tags: spring-boot, testing, junit5, pact

I can't get the pact provider tests to run on any other port than 8080 when using jUnit5. I have the following code:

```
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@Provider(PROVIDER)
@PactFolder("pacts")
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
public class PactProviderTest {

  @LocalServerPort private int serverPort;

  @Autowired Result<IServiceManagementFacade2> serviceManagementFacade;

  @Autowired private RestServiceFactory restServiceFactory;

  @TestTemplate
  @ExtendWith(PactVerificationInvocationContextProvider.class)
  void pactVerificationTestTemplate(PactVerificationContext context) {
    context.setTarget(new HttpTestTarget("localhost", serverPort));
    context.verifyInteraction();
  }
```

When I run this I get the following error:

```
Request Failed - Connect to localhost:8080 [localhost/127.0.0.1, localhost/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1] failed: Connection refused (Connection refused)
```

If I change

> @SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)

to

> @SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = WebEnvironment.DEFINED_PORT)

the tests pass. But then no other app can be running on that port during the tests which is not acceptable in the test environment. Any ideas how I can solve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I managed to solve it.

Moving the line:

context.setTarget(new HttpTestTarget("localhost", serverPort));

to a @BeforeEach resolved the issue. The reason it didn't work then I tried to do it previously is because I was using a variable to set it.

So doing something like this:

```
  @LocalServerPort private int serverPort;
  private HttpTestTarget target = new HttpTestTarget("localhost", serverPort);

  @TestTemplate
  @ExtendWith(PactVerificationInvocationContextProvider.class)
  void pactVerificationTestTemplate(PactVerificationContext context) {
    context.verifyInteraction();
  }

  @BeforeEach
  void setTarget(PactVerificationContext context) {
    context.setTarget(target);
  }
```

doesn't work.

This however does work:

```
  @LocalServerPort private int serverPort;

  @TestTemplate
  @ExtendWith(PactVerificationInvocationContextProvider.class)
  void pactVerificationTestTemplate(PactVerificationContext context) {
    context.verifyInteraction();
  }

  @BeforeEach
  void setTarget(PactVerificationContext context) {
    context.setTarget(new HttpTestTarget("localhost", serverPort));
  }
```

Comment: I followed the same but getting status mismatch error expected status of 201 but was 404